# runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "python3 app.py": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: python, docker

I don't have any PATH specified in the .Dockerfile but having below error. Please check below. Any help is highly appreciated.

My docker file looks like this:

```
# Set the base image to Python 3.9
FROM python:3.9

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

# Set environment variables
ENV SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL ${SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL}

# Make port 80 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 80

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD ["python3", "app.py"]



[5/Oct/2023:11:05:30] [deployment:16] Finalizing your deployment
[5/Oct/2023:11:05:45] [deployment:17] Creating your deployment
[5/Oct/2023:11:09:11] runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "python3 app.py": executable file not found in $PATH
[5/Oct/2023:11:09:34] [deployment:17] Node crashed; container "app": CannotStartContainerError: ResourceInitializationError: failed to create new container runtime task: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "python3 app.py": executable file not
[5/Oct/2023:11:10:04] [deployment:17] Started 1 new node
[5/Oct/2023:11:10:36] [deployment:17] Took too long
[5/Oct/2023:11:10:44] runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "python3 app.py": executable file not found in $PATH
[5/Oct/2023:11:17:09] [deployment:16] Finalizing your deployment
[5/Oct/2023:11:17:28] [deployment:18] Creating your deployment
[5/Oct/2023:11:19:44] [deployment:18] Reached a steady state
[5/Oct/2023:11:24:40] [deployment:18] Finalizing your deployment
[5/Oct/2023:11:25:00] [deployment:19] Creating your deployment
[5/Oct/2023:11:26:31] [deployment:19] Reached a steady state
```

Comment: How are you launching the container?  The error message would be consistent with an array-syntax command having only a single shell word, but your Dockerfile `CMD` looks right.  (Also consider setting a shebang line at the top of your script and making it executable, so you don't need to explicitly say `python3` in the command line.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm deploying to AWS Lightsail Container using Github action. Here is the action file: https://pastebin.com/x2skxJR2

Comment: @DavidMaze It's was an app for scrapping data from web. Despite showing the error in log, the app is working as I'm receiving notification for the scrapping.